# Draw a polygon that satisfies this criterion

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation

Draw a picture of a simple polygon and a set of guards, such that the guards can see every point on every edge of the polygon, but the guards cannot see every point in the interior of the polygon.

I encountered this while randomly searching for polygon triangulation problems. I feel that no such polygon + guard combination exists. but I do not know how to go about proving or disproving that. Some help would be appreciated.

Source: Page 17, Problem 1(a) on [this document](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/754/Handouts/cmsc754-nosol.pdf)

Comment: A slight explanation of how to form such a polygon would be enough. I cannot find a way to do so. This isn't homework.

Comment: Ok, I have added some context now.

Comment: Have you seen [this book](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ArtGalleryTheorems/art.html)?

Comment: I have an example of this, but I do not know how to include images in an answer. If anybody tells me how, I will draw it (can I do this directly in LaTeX?).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I have found the solution. Should I update the answer myself ?

Comment: It seems that I cannot answer my own question, but [here's a solution](http://i.imgur.com/6OFMl.png), taken from the [book](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ArtGalleryTheorems/art.html) shared by J.M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. Yellow stars are the guards. They cannot see the red object.

[image]